# Why the second command works and why not first? what is the difference?

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

I encounter below strange problem in my shell script.

When i execute like below it doesn't work:

```
excom='/Development/temp_try/testing/\* -o -path /Development/temp_try/testing1/\*'
findcom=$(find /Development/temp_try ! \( -path $excom \) -type f \( ! -name \*.HPSEPFQDN.\* ! -name \*.HPSEPIPCHG.\* \) -exec grep -lF "corp.abc.com" {} \;)
```

Where as if i execute like below, it works fine:

```
findcom=$(find /Development/temp_try ! \( -path /Development/temp_try/testing/\* -o -path /Development/temp_try/testing1/\* \) -type f \( ! -name \*.HPSEPFQDN.\* ! -name \*.HPSEPIPCHG.\* \) -exec grep -lF "corp.abc.com" {} \;)
```

First one output is:

```
/Development/temp_try/f1
/Development/temp_try/f2
/Development/temp_try/f3
/Development/temp_try/f4
/Development/temp_try/f5
/Development/temp_try/f6
/Development/temp_try/f7
/Development/temp_try/f8
/Development/temp_try/try10
/Development/temp_try/log_test
/Development/temp_try/try10v
/Development/temp_try/try10v1
/Development/temp_try/try10j
/Development/temp_try/try10j1
/Development/temp_try/testing1/f1
/Development/temp_try/testing1/f2
/Development/temp_try/testing1/f3
/Development/temp_try/testing/test1/f1
/Development/temp_try/testing/test1/f2
/Development/temp_try/testing/test1/f3
/Development/temp_try/testing/test1/f4
/Development/temp_try/testing/test1/f5
/Development/temp_try/testing/test1/f6
/Development/temp_try/testing/test1/f7
/Development/temp_try/testing/test1/f8
/Development/temp_try/testing/f1
/Development/temp_try/testing/f2
/Development/temp_try/testing/f3
/Development/temp_try/testing/f4
/Development/temp_try/testing/f5
/Development/temp_try/testing/f6
/Development/temp_try/testing/f7
/Development/temp_try/testing/f8
/Development/temp_try/try10j1_working
/Development/temp_try/try11
/Development/temp_try/try11_original
/Development/temp_try/try8
```

where as the second one output is:

```
/Development/temp_try/f1
/Development/temp_try/f2
/Development/temp_try/f3
/Development/temp_try/f4
/Development/temp_try/f5
/Development/temp_try/f6
/Development/temp_try/f7
/Development/temp_try/f8
/Development/temp_try/try10
/Development/temp_try/log_test
/Development/temp_try/try10v
/Development/temp_try/try10v1
/Development/temp_try/try10j
/Development/temp_try/try10j1
/Development/temp_try/try10j1_working
/Development/temp_try/try11
/Development/temp_try/try11_original
/Development/temp_try/try8
```

Second one perfectly excludes the directories where as first doesn't. I have no clue how they both differ....

Thanks for Answers and comments, Now i understand the issue, could solve the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

filepath="/Development/temp_try"
searchstring="corp.abc.com"

while read exfile
do
lasc=${exfile##${exfile%%?}}
if [ "$lasc" = "/" ]; then
exfile="$exfile*"
fi
if [ "$excom" = "" ]; then
excom="$exfile"
else
#excom="$excom -o -path '$exfile'"
set -A excom "$excom" '-o' '-path' "$exfile"
fi
done <input4


echo "The exclude command is ${excom[@]}"
findcom=$(find $filepath ! \( -path "${excom[@]}" \) -type f \( ! -name \*.HPSEPFQDN.\* ! -name \*.HPSEPIPCHG.\* \) -exec grep -lF $searchstring {} \;)
for filename in $findcom
do
echo $filename
done
```

My input4 file contains below lines:

```
/Development/temp_try/testing/
/Development/temp_try/testing1/
```

Comment: Try `\( -path "$excom" \)`

Comment: because `'\*'` means `\*` literal while `\*` in plain bash really means `*`.

Comment: The value of a parameter expansion does not undergo quote removal, so the backslash is retained as a literal character in the argument to `find`, as pointed out by @HuStmpHrrr. It's the same reason that `excom='".../*"'` wouldn't work. Quoted strings in shell are just a shortcut for backslash-escaping every character in the string. `"\*"` is the same as `\\\*`.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: See also BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Thanks @Charles Duffy . BashFAQ is something i have been looking for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store command line (fully or partially) in simple variables as it creates many issues at the time of variable expansion in shell.

Better to store in shell arrays like this

```
excom=('/Development/temp_try/testing/*' -o -path '/Development/temp_try/testing1/*')
findcom=$(find /Development/temp_try ! \( -path "${excom[@]}" \) -type f \( ! -name \*.HPSEPFQDN.\* ! -name \*.HPSEPIPCHG.\* \) -exec grep -lF "corp.abc.com" {} \;)
```

Comment: Acceptance is actually tick mark on top-left the answer.  That tick mark turns green when you click on it.

Comment: I just did that and it shows green. Your post was useful and accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Inside a single-quoted string, `\` has no special significance. So the result of

```
excom='/Development/temp_try/testing/\* -o -path /Development/temp_try/testing1/\*'
```

is that the value of `excom` will include two backslash characters.

Backslash characters are not special in filename expansions, so when the value of `$excom` is filename-expanded and wordsplit (because its expansion is not quoted), the backslash characters continue to be ordinary characters. So the expansion of

```
find /Development/temp_try ! \( -path $excom \) ...
```

has the literal words:

```
find
/Development/temp_try
!
(
-path
/Development/temp_try/testing/\*
-o
-path
/Development/temp_try/testing1/\*
```

Nothing matches the pattern `/Development/temp_try/testing/\*` because your filenames do not include backslashes.

Had you left out the backslashes when you defined excom:

```
excom='/Development/temp_try/testing/* -o -path /Development/temp_try/testing1/*'
```

then the filename patterns would have been expanded in the invocation of find. In this case, `find /Development/temp_try ! \( -path $excom \) ...` would expand to:

```
find
/Development/temp_try
!
(
-path
/Development/temp_try/testing/f1
/Development/temp_try/testing/f2
/Development/temp_try/testing/f3
...
```

which is also not what you want, since the `-path` predicate needs to be followed by exactly one pattern, not by a list of filenames.

Consequently, you need to pass the value of `excom` as a list of quoted words. The only simple way to do that in bash is to use an array, because you can expand an array into a list of quoted array values:

```
excom=("/Development/temp_try/testing/*"
       -o -path "/Development/temp_try/testing1/*")
findcom=$(find /Development/temp_try ! \( -path "${excom[@]}" \) \
          -type f \( ! -name "*.HPSEPFQDN.*" ! -name "*.HPSEPIPCHG."* \) \
          -exec grep -lF "corp.abc.com" {} \;)
```

(That definition of `findcom`, which is not quoted, assumes that no filename produced by the `-exec grep` command will have whitespace or a pattern metacharacter in its name. In general, that's not a safe assumption.)

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks.